# How do I add event listeners for ruby methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to implement an event listener on a button that depends on whether or not a user is signed in or not? Is there a way to integrate this code in rails.  For instance, if a user clicks the "Love-it" button for an object and they're signed in, the information of the object is saved to the database.  If they're not signed in, the same "love-it" button should redirect them to the sign-in form.  Please be as detailed as possible.  Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're going to need to sprinkle some JavaScript in your app in order to have an event send information back to the server. Unfortunately your question is way too broad for Stack Overflow. I would explore Javascript a little and come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you are adding the "Love It" button on an article.

```
= link_to("Love It!", like_article_path(@article))
```

Now in the `ArticleController` add a `before_filter` to enforce the authentication requirement ( assuming 
you are using a gem like `Devise` for authentication)

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController    
  before_filter :authenticate_user!    
  def like
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.likes.create(:user => current_user)
  end    
end
```